# Windows Phone - failing to get a string from a website with login information

Tags: c#, php, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am new to accessing web services with Windows Phone 7/8. I'm using a WebClient to get a string from a php-website. The site returns a JSON string but at the moment I'm just trying to put it into a TextBox as a normal string just to test if the connection works.

The php-page requires an authentication and I think that's where my code is failing. Here's my code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myUsername", "myPassword");
client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://www.mywebsite.com/ba/php/jsonstuff.php"));

void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string data = e.Result;
        this.jsonText.Text = data;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This returns first a WebException and then a TargetInvocationException. If I replace the Uri with for example "http://www.google.com/index.html" the jsonText TextBox gets filled with html text from Google (oddly enough, this also works even when the WebClient credentials are still set).

So is the problem in the setting of the credentials? I couldn't find any good results when searching for guides on how to access php-pages with credentials, only without them. Then I found a short mention somewhere to use the WebClient.Credentials property. But should it work some other way?

**Update:** here's what I can get out of the WebException (sorry for the bad formatting):

System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.     --->System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)

**Update 2:** Here's the error log line:

Nov 16 17:51:12 myservice httpd[21036]: 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Nov/2012:17:51:12 +0200] "GET /ba/php/jsonstuff.php?origpath=/ba/php/jsonstuff.php HTTP/1.1" 401 290 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"

401 I guess would suggest false credentials?

Comment: what kind of auth does that php page require? you're setting http basic auth, which will do nothing in the php page requires a session cookie established via a login form.

Comment: There's no login form. When the user goes to the said url he gets a normal browser popup requesting for credentials.

Comment: all right, that's basic auth then. check the server's error log to see if there's anything about why your wp8 request is being rejected.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to access the error log myself. It's a project partners service and I don't have access to the server, I was just given that address to test the connection on. If there's nothing wrong with my code then I'm going to contact them, but I'm just trying to make sure everything is OK in my end before doing that. Could response time be the problem? I noticed that when accessing the page with a normal browser it takes about 10 seconds before the JSON text is returned.

Comment: You need the log if you want assistance with trying to decide if the code to blame.

Comment: That's what I thought too. I'll get back to you on the error log! But any comments on the code? Should the authentication be so straightforward as to just set it on the WebClient.Credentials?

Comment: Updated the original post with WebException information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found a way to get this working. The problem was that the WebClient class couldn't properly handle the cookies of the web service.

After some Google searches I found this solution and it works perfectly:
http://firebelly.net/post/3341374382/cookie-aware-webclient-for-wp7

So basically you just make your own client class that extends the WebClient class which can store cookies.

Answer (score 0):

In my opininion you really need to see how the server handles your request. "NotFound" in WebException could mean that you're referring to a location that doesn't exist. But I'm sure that you pass the right URL. So there must be some logic on the server that redirects you.
If you go to the url using your desktop browser - do you have any kind of SSL certificate error or warning? Maybe that's the reason. Try navigating on your phone using IE.
Or you could set up another host just to give it a try.

I'll set up a host on my machine and try it.

The problem is with the SSL certificate I guess. WP is very strict when it goes to checking SSL certificates, so you should try without ssl or install cert on your emulator/phone or install valid (not self generated) cert on your server.

Comment: I don't remember getting an SSL error/warning. I tried navigating to the page with the emulator browser and it asked me for authentication just like a PC browser did. Only weird thing is that instead of displaying the JSON text, the emulator browser shows a document icon and a text "tap to open". However when tapping the screen nothing happens. Also, I'm trying to get access to the error logs, just might take some time since it's weekend now :)

Comment: I also tried getting the ResponseUri from the WebException and it returned <original uri>?origpath=/ba/php/jsonstuff.php so I guess there's some redirecting happening. Since I'm new to web services I'm not sure if this is supposed to mean something?

Comment: Try using network sniffing tool to see to communication. I'm not sure but you should be able to monitor HTTP traffic using Fiddler. Even if the request is made on WP emulator. Not sure how it will handle SSL though. You can also setup local web service (on your machine) and try to use you app with it. Also there is quite a lot information about "NotFound" exception os stackoverflow. Look for it, some may be helpfull. I've managed to recreate your issue and in my cas it was the self-signed cert.

Comment: I received an error log line from my project partner about the access attempt. I added it to the original post. I also checked installed certificates on my Firefox browser and didn't see any installed from that website. I'll still ask and make sure they aren't using any SSL certification.

Comment: So apparently there is SSL in use and also Server Name Indication. The certificate is gotten from an official source and it's not self-signed. I found this SO-question and tried the answer but still receive a WebException: [windows-phone-7-download-xml-over-ssl-with-authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763500/windows-phone-7-download-xml-over-ssl-with-authentication/3234248#3234248)

Comment: And it's pretty much the same problem I'm facing.